# Make the background of the navigation bar to change when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visual-web-developer

I have a navigation bar on a website that i am making. I want to change the colour of the bar after the page scrolls about 500 pixels. How would i code that using javascript?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] so you can receive an adequate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a scroll-eventlistener (using jQuery) which checks if the scrollposition is reached and then do some action.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if(window.scrollY>500)
    { 
        //change color
    }
})
```